# How come the angle for cross and dot equations are not equivalent in these equations?

Tags: vectors, cross-product, angle

Finding the angle between two lines

Given lines:
$$l_1 = [3, 1, -1] + t[2, -2, 3]$$
$$l_2 = [5, -1, 2] + t[1, -3, 5]$$

I tried cross product equation of finding the angle:
$\cos^{-1}(\sqrt{426} / (\sqrt{17} \times \sqrt{35})) = 57.8$ degree

Then I tried dot product equation of finding the angle:
$\sin^{-1}(23 / (\sqrt{17} \times \sqrt{35})) = 19.5$ degree

The correct answer is the latter dot product equation, but I don't understand why the cross product equation failed me in this instance.

Can someone clarify this for me? Thanks.

Comment: According to my calculations, your $426$ should be $66$, because $(2,-2,3)\times(1,-3,5)=(-1,-7,-4)$ and $1^2+7^2+4^2=66$.

Comment: I don't know why I made that mistake and did not see it. I feel stupid. Thank you though.

Comment: don't feel stupid that's useless and self harmful. learn that's useful and helpful to everyone.

Comment: You also wrote $\cos^{-1}$ where you meant $\sin^{-1}$ and $\sin^{-1}$ where you meant $\cos^{-1}$. But you actually used the correct functions in your calculations, so most likely the names just got swapped while copying them here.